# Async await, code never getting executed

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Im having this method to commit changes to an `eventstore`, and then publishing the events after the `eventstore` has gotten updated.
My problem is that the code never reach the `aggregate.MarkChangesAsCommitted` method and the next `await`.

```
    public async Task CommitChanges()
    {
        foreach (var aggregate in _trackedAggregates.Values)
        {
            var newEvents = aggregate.GetChanges();
            await _eventStorage.Save(aggregate.Id, newEvents);
            aggregate.MarkChangesAsCommitted();
            await _eventPublisher.Publish(newEvents);
        }
    }
```

**Event store**

```
    public Task Save(Guid aId, IEnumerable<IDomainEvent> events)
    {
        return new Task(() =>
        {
            using (var stream = _store.OpenStream(aId))
            {
                foreach (var domainEvent in events)
                {
                    stream.Add(new EventMessage
                    {
                        Body = domainEvent
                    });
                }
                stream.CommitChanges(Guid.NewGuid());
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Do you await CommitChanges?

Comment: Then the awaitable that `_eventStorage.Save` returns is never completing. Given that we have no knowledge of what type `_eventStorage` is, and so no knowledge of what the `Save` method is, there's really not enough in this question for us to hazard a guess at an answer.

Comment: I think you have a valid point here, it seems that the save-method never completes. Thank you:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new Task()` doesn't start the task, you need to then call `task.Start()` to start it. `Task.Run` returns an already started task, also called a hot task.

Answer (score 0):

Changed return new Task to return Task.Run, that solved it